# Input field hidden dynamically can not be shown later

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, textinput

I have a form with a text input and a radio button pair used to select yes/no. For purposes of keeping this simple, the radio button click event checks the value and if yes, it shows the input text field. If no, it hides the input field. I also check the initial state on document ready and show/hide the input text field.

I find that clicking No results in the input hiding using a jQuery .hide() method. But when I select Yes the resulting .show() method call does not show the input. If I set the radio to Yes and then refresh the page then the input shows up just fine.

Firebug show no input tag. It's like clicking No radio deleted the input from the DOM.

Here's the JS code sample:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#cost_sharing_yes').attr('checked') == 'checked') {
            $('input#Institutional_CS_TP').show();
        } else {
            $('input#Institutional_CS_TP').hide();
        }

        $('#cost_sharing_yes').click(function() {
            $('input[id="Institutional_CS_TP"]').show();
        });
        $('#cost_sharing_no').click(function() {
            $('input#Institutional_CS_TP').fadeOut("fast");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try if ($("#cost_sharing_yes").is(":checked")){}
also noticed fadeOut .. shouldn't make a difference but use hide() .. might have issue with opacity or something

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `)` for closing ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

} // <--
```

For getting the `checked` property of the inputs perperly you should use `prop` method instead of `attr`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var isChecked = $('#cost_sharing_yes').prop('checked');
   $('#Institutional_CS_TP').toggle(isChecked);
   // ..
})
```

Comment: The prop() method is only used if your using jQuery >1.6. In previous versions of jQuery attr() was used to manipulate "checked".

Comment: @Dracs That's true, `attr` was error-prone and they created this method which should be used for dealing with properties.

Comment: Yes in the quoted example I provided i forgot to add the closing ) char. I have tried modifying my code to use the .prop method rather than the .attr but this doesn't resolve my problem of the input not being shown when it should. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. It was a self-inflicted coding problem.
To keep the example simple I had removed another function call in the mix that I didn't think had any bearing on the problem. I was wrong. In that function I had

```
    $('td#Institutional_CS_TP).text('$0');
    $('input[name="Institutional_CS_TP"]').val('0.00');
```

This resulted in only the td value showing, not the input inside that same td.
Both my td and the input tags inside the td had the same ID values...not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**html code**

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">

    Value Based<input type="radio" name="cars"  value="2"  />

    Percent Based<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />
    <br>
    <div id="Cars2" class="desc" style="display: none;">
        <br>
        <label for="txtPassportNumber">Commission Value</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" class="form-control" name="commision_value" />
    </div>
    <div id="Cars3" class="desc" style="display: none;">
        <br>
        <label for="txtPassportNumber">Commission Percent</label>
       <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" class="form-control" name="commision_percent" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}

function myFunction1() {
    var y = document.getElementById("myInput1");
    if (y.type === "password") {
        y.type = "text";
    } else {
        y.type = "password";
    }
}
```